# Greensock Draggable Scroll (Drag n Flick)

Tags: scroll, draggable, drag, gsap

Why this code is not working??
I'm using BootStrap, AngularJS and GreenSock

In this example I'm using only GreenSock, but doesn't work too:

Example: [JSFinddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3t6q1hme/7/)

```
Draggable.create("#scroller", {type:"scroll", edgeResistance:0.5, throwProps:true});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my first StackOverflow answer :)

Looks like your JSFiddle wasn't accessing the proper TweenLight, Draggable, and CSSPlugin CDNs.

The way to fix it – update the CDNS you're using. On the left-hand side panel, under External Resources, remove the existing TweenLite.min.js, Draggable.min.js, and CSSPlugin.min.js.

Then add instead:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/TweenLite.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/plugins/CSSPlugin.min.js

(See below for the third link. I can't post more than 2 links yet bc I don't have 10 reputation unfortunately.)

That should work! Hope this helped!

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.16.1/utils/Draggable.min.js is the third link.